# Позиционирование подсказки при разбиении на строки

Tags: javascript, css

Не могу понять, как настроить положение появляющейся подсказки.

Если сообщение длинное и разбивается на 2 и более строк в узком окне, подсказка появляется под курсором мыши и  при малейшем её движении, начинает исчезать/появляться.

В примере ниже, видимо из-за особенностей редактора, такого не происходит.

```js
var showingTooltip;

document.onmouseover = function(e) {
  var target = e.target;

  var tooltip = target.getAttribute('data-tooltip');
  if (!tooltip) return;

  var tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
  tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip';
  tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltip;
  
  document.body.appendChild(tooltipElem);

  var coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  var left = coords.left + (target.offsetWidth - tooltipElem.offsetWidth) / 2;
  if (left < 0) left = 0; // не вылезать за левую границу окна

  var top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
  if (top < 0) { // не вылезать за верхнюю границу окна
    top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
  }

  tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';

  showingTooltip = tooltipElem;
};

document.onmouseout = function(e) {

  if (showingTooltip) {
    document.body.removeChild(showingTooltip);
    showingTooltip = null;
  }

};

document.onmousedown = function(e) {

  if (showingTooltip) {
    document.body.removeChild(showingTooltip);
    showingTooltip = null;
  }

};
```

```html
<div data-tooltip='Если сообщение длинное и разбивается на 2 и более строк в узком окне, подсказка появляется под курсором мыши и  при малейшем её движении, начинает исчезать/появляться'>
  Наведи сюда
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```js
document.onmouseout = function(e) {

  if (showingTooltip && showingTooltip!=e.relatedTarget) {
document.body.removeChild(showingTooltip);
showingTooltip = null;
  }

};
```